# And operator for GitLab `only` pipeline directive

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am aware of the fact that one can run a GitLab pipeline only when a certain condition is satisfied, eg. only when the branch is `master` or only when a Git Tag is created.

For example:

```
stages:
  - greet

greet_job:
  stage: greet
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "Hello!"
```

This runs the `greet_job` job only when the branch is called `master`.

I would like to combine *two* conditions with a logical and, ie. I would like to run a pipeline, say, only when the branch is called `master` *and* a new Git Tag has been created. Is that possible?

**ADDED**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796018/how-to-run-a-gitlab-ci-yml-job-only-on-a-tagged-branch) I found a possible solution:

```
  - greet

greet_job:
  stage: greet
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - tags
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
  script:
    - echo "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build fairly complex conditions with [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules), which you use should anyway as work on `only`/`except` is discontinued.

You can combine two conditions in rules with the `&&` operator, so e.g. run the job only on merge-requests and if `$CUSTOM_VARIABLE` is true.

```
 rules:
    - if: '$CUSTOM_VARIABLE == "true" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

But checking if the branch is master and a tag was created is not trivial, as there are no predefined varariables for the branch from which a tag was created.

So if you only create tags from master, checking if the pipeline is a tag pipeline wpuld be sufficient.

```
stages:
  - greet

greet_job:
  stage: greet
  script:
    - echo "Hello!"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
```

Comment: The practice is actually slightly different: tags are created on a branch called `develop`, which is then merged into `master`.

Comment: Would it be possible to automatically merge `develop` into `master` (and consequently run a pipeline) each time that a tag is created on `develop` itself?

Comment: It would be possible but tricky. You can take a look at this answer how to merge a branch in a pipeline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113402/how-can-i-make-gitlab-runner-merge-code-into-a-branch-on-a-successful-build